# Our/us etc before -ing form

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

> (..) those who stand to profit from **our** working harder,

I've noticed this pattern very often, but I don't know how or when to use it. The following

> (...) those who stand to profit from **us** working harder,

would be right as well, right? Is there a difference in meaning? Or in context of use maybe? Thanks in advance!

For reference, the sentence is taken from the fourth paragraph from the end in [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/dec/22/why-time-management-is-ruining-our-lives).

Comment: Context of use it is: the preference for possessive *our* over objective *us* with the gerund *working,* for specifying who is doing this working, is characteristic of formal register.

Comment: @BrianDonovan okay, so they mean the same but our is more formal? Thanks a lot! That's the kind of stuff they don't teach you in high school English

Answer (score -1):

As [@BrianDonovan](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/76878) notes in [their comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364764/our-us-etc-before-ing-form#comment850182_364764), this comes down to the context in which it is used:

> "the preference for possessive our over objective us with the gerund
>   working, for specifying who is doing this working, is characteristic
>   of formal register."

Comment: Isn't it site policy to convert comments to answers when one thinks that that's what they _should_ be using Community wikis rather than as personal answers piggybacking on others' submissions? In this case, I'll be back to downvote an answer to a well-known multi-duplicate (which _shouldn't_ be 'answered') unless this is deleted.

Comment: @Chappo Hasn't Forgotten Monica I downvoted on the basis that copying and pasting others' comments is a cheap way to get awards. All you need do is vote up Brian Donovan's answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth perhaps you might get down from your pulpit and consider that mine was an innocent mistake. I've been quietly cleaning up the many *hundreds* of unanswered low-quality questions that are over 3 years old but avoided being auto-deleted after the first 12 months because someone happened to give them a single upvote. They linger unproductively in our library. If they have one comment or less, I downvote them and they get auto-deleted within 10 days. If they have 2 comments, even a zero score isn't enough for auto-delete to work, so I VTC many of these, but I don't want to flood...

Comment: ...our review queues, so many of them I DV and leave for a later clean-up. And sometimes I find a question that seems interesting, and I upvote it and star it for me to come back to and write up a quality answer. A small number of questions had comments that constituted a reasonable answer, so on the weekend I decided to create a quick answer to a few of them. To be honest, if this is frowned upon and the answers DV'd then I will simply delete those answers and go back to my old approach, which was to eliminate most questions without attempting to rescue the better ones. To you & @Greybeard...

Comment: ...I'm prepared to put in the extra work in adding value to our library but I expect at least a small reward for the effort involved (in addition to my 20 close votes per day & other work on the review queues), so I'm not prepared to do community wikis. @Greybeard's comment about a "cheap way to get awards" is a cheap, unwarranted and unfair attack.

Comment: @Greybeard BTW, what do you mean "All you need do is vote up Brian Donovan's answer?" Note that the question was closed as a dupe *after* I posted my answer, so I was entirely unaware of any answer by Brian. I couldn't care less about your DV, but the suggestion that I was purely chasing rep points is unfair, unfounded, ignorant and hurtful.

Comment: @Chappo Hasn't Forgotten Monica - Imagine you give a comment that I think is, in fact a brilliant answer. My action would to be to vote up your comment and add a comment that you should promote your comment to an answer. I would find it wrong to copy your answer as **my** answer.It seems little different from saying "I have copied this book from Project Gutenberg - you can copy this - please send me $10."

Comment: If you do so much tidying of the site, one would have thought you'd CV as a (multi-)duplicate you recognise instead of adding yet another answer. // Register is involved, though it's not the whole story. The ACC-ing construction focuses more on the doer and the POSS-ing on the action, so some would ignore register and choose the emphasis they wanted.

Comment: //// Also, perhaps you should take up your stance with the moderator @MetaEd, who [has written in a similar situation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456925/what-is-the-meaning-of-skrt): 'Avoid copying an answer from elsewhere. “You have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text … is not your work”.'  I've flagged comments I've thought worth preserving for moderators to decide whether to convert to wikis. Takes less time than copy-and-paste.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth your last point ["I've flagged comments I've thought worth preserving for moderators to decide whether to convert to wikis. Takes less time than copy-and-paste"] offers an excellent way forward. Thank you.

Comment: @Greybeard that approach makes sense for new(-ish) comments. It doesn't really work for comments that are over three years old: I've tried it. This was a **dead** question, stuck in our library without an answer. The best option would have been to delete it, but I don't have the rep for that. The next best option would have been to CV it, but I'd used up all my CVs for the day. I should have left it for the next day & looked for a dupe; I'll know better next time. Perhaps you could spend some time down here in the EL&U wasteland clearing out old rubbish, to get an idea of what's involved...

Comment: @Greybeard ... try [this filter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=MostVotes&filters=NoAnswers&uqlId=3&page=38) to see the oldest unanswered questions with score of 1 and consider what you would do with each. :-)

Comment: @Chappo Hasn't Forgotten Monica I'm a little clearer on what you are trying to do. Flagging seems to be passing the buck – somebody will still have to do the tidying. SE's system does not allow for members who can’t delete to be as helpful as you intended to be. I also suspect that a lot of comments are taken as answers anyway or that the question has been answered elsewhere. My final point is “Does it matter that a question is unanswered?” I suspect that, if it were thought necessary, a line or two of code could be inserted to automatically delete unanswered questions after, say, one year.