# What is the meaning of 'skrt'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, slang, pop-culture

I've been learning English for many years and recently found this word 'skrt'.

I think people with hip hop background use this word a lot. And some use it as an adjective. From my understanding this word is a mimetic word, which has similar meaning of 'cool' or 'awesome'.

Can someone explain more about this 'skrt' word? What's its true meaning, how to use it, etc.

Thanks a lot.

Edit: Just found out that 'skr skr' is a misspelling of 'skrt skrt'. It is commonly used in hip hop culture.

Comment: Do you have an example? Urban Dictionary has an entry for [skr](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=skr) where the top definition defines it as what looks to be an onomatopoeia that is used when someone makes a crazy suggestion. Without context it's impossible to say if it's the same word or something else.

Comment: One example: from a pop star Kris Wu who is a Chinese Canadian, he said something like: "This rapper is 'skrt'" when he's commenting some rapper.

Comment: Looks like a real English word to me, here's its entry in The Right Rhymes (a historical dictionary of hip-hop), with 39 citations between 1994 and 2016 
 https://www.therightrhymes.com/skrt/

Comment: @Hugo But is a dictionary of hip-hop a dictionary of English? I can't find "skrt" in any English dictionary.

Comment: @CJDennis Yes, a dictionary of hip-hop is a dictionary of (a subset of) English. ["This is a dictionary of hip-hop language."](https://www.therightrhymes.com/#about)

Comment: @Hugo In that case it should go on Hip Hop Stack Exchange.

Comment: You need to give some examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there is some dispute, it appears to be an onomatopoeic word, relating to the sound of car tyres when setting off rapidly or drifting; hence implying the ownership of an expensive car.

e.g. from the song "[Skrt](https://genius.com/Kodak-black-skrt-lyrics)" by Kodak Black (2016)

```
Stick and move, then I SKRT, SKRT, SKRT SKRT, SKRT (Ooh I'm gone)
....
SKRT, SKRT, SKRT, SKRT, SKRT Jump in that Jag, SKRT, SKRT, SKRT SKRT,
SKRT, SKRT, SKRT, SKRT
```

It is less clear in "[Skrt Skrt](https://genius.com/Tory-lanez-skrt-skrt-lyrics)" by Tory Lanez (2018).  In this case "skrt" appears to be the contrasted with "stop", hence it could be assumed that it has been extended to mean to start up, or to get going.

```
'Cause I like freaking
You like sex on the weekend
Me, too, me, too
'Cause I like drinking
You looking at me winking
Me, too, me, too
So give me the work
So give me the work
You gon' make me skrt skrt
You gon' make me stop stop
So give me the work
So give me the work
You gon' make me skrt skrt
You gon' make me stop stop
```

A discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/teenagers/comments/65t7x3/what_does_skrt_skrt_mean/) (OK, not the most reliable of sources, but it does reflect a wider understanding), includes the following definitions:

- I believe it's the sound of drifting in a fast car
- Pulling up wildly on a ride so the wheels go SKKRRRRRT. Aka drifting.
- Its like when the tires squeal in a car, so saying it implies that you have a really fast, expensive car

Comment: Interesting, I had just thought it was onomatopoetic for records grinding

Comment: "@JamesRandom Yes, by implication. "Words" from (pop) lyrics are OT *per se*. – Kris 31 mins ago"

Comment: @Kris Does "OT" mean "on topic" or "off topic"?

Answer (score 2):

Skrt is a reference to the sound tires make when burning out prior to leaving in a hurry. In the '90's a common phrase used was "I'm gonna Skrt Out!"

Answer (score 0):

> SKRT stands for Ski Kayak Ripaille Team.
>   —*Acronym Finder*

> [It] is an important term in hip-hop, rap, and modern culture. Used by many rappers.
>
> Nowadays, used as a slang word to express excitement and humor. Often used as "skrt skrt" with a minor voice crack.
>   —*Urban Dictionary*

This is an example:

> [John]: "Check out my new car!"
>   [Melissa]: "Pretty [...]"
>   [John]: "skrt skrt"
>   —*Urban Dictionary*

Comment: I doubt "Ski Kayak Ripaille Team" has anything to do with the original question.

Comment: Avoid copying an answer from elsewhere. “[You have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text … is not your work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077 "“Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?” – SE Meta")”. Also, avoid borrowing from another work without [crediting the author and the work](/help/referencing "“[How to reference material written by others]” – EL&U Help").

Comment: i dont know why are you taking like this?i was just trying to help,i had the same question before and just wrote the same thing other answered to me,i wasnt sure,but i wanted to help ok ?

Comment: @Mona Stack Exchange sites are not like other question and answer sites on the net. Stack Exchange has higher standards of journalistic integrity. Its standards are similar to those that apply in many academic or professional environments. The difference does sometimes take some getting used to.

Comment: @Mona I appreciate your effort and enthusiasm. Apparently you are pretty new around here, and also apparently not a native speaker of the English language (always use capital "I" in written English). I'd suggest that you visit this site regularly and get familiar with how it works. Then you can post answers and get reputation. Good Luck.